# PDF layers don't show

Tags: luatex, ocg, xwatermark

I'm trying to show the watermark as a background layer so the reader may have the option to either see the background or not. I'm using the `LuaLaTeX` and the `xwatermark` package. When I compile the script neither the background appears nor the layer. Here's a MWE of my script:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{ArnoPro-Regular}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \disablehyphenation

\usepackage[
    hmarginratio = 1:1,
    left = 3cm,
    right = 2cm,
    top = 3cm,
    bottom = 2cm,
    headheight = 15pt
    ]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{rowgrey}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
    \definecolor{heavengreen}{rgb}{.8901,.9568,.8941}
    \definecolor{greeen}{HTML}{7cc576}
    \definecolor{gold}{HTML}{f9ad81}
    \definecolor{smoofie}{HTML}{fff7ea}

\usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepackage[printwatermark,watermarkparser=|]{xwatermark}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \pagecolor{smoofie}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{4cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[line width=2mm,draw=greeen] (0,0) circle (4cm);
            \draw[line width=2mm,draw=gold] (0,0) circle (2cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\begin{ocg}{Background}{background}{true}
    \newwatermark[pages=1-5,angle=0,scale=2,xpos=0cm,ypos=0cm]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=.2]
            \fill [heavengreen] (-12,-5) rectangle (7,15);
            \draw[line width=2mm,draw=greeen,fill=heavengreen] (0,0) circle (4cm);
            \draw[line width=2mm,draw=gold] (0,0) circle (2cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
\end{ocg}

\sloppy

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably the layer should be defined inside the watermark, not the other way round: `\newwatermark[...]{\begin{ocg} ... \end{ocg}}`

Comment: It worked just for the first page. The following ones show the background but not the option to deactivate the layer.

Comment: Okay, now it's fully functional! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The layer should be defined inside the watermark, not the other way round:

```
\newwatermark[pages=1-5,angle=0,scale=2,xpos=0cm,ypos=0cm]{%
    \begin{ocg}{Background}{background}{true}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=.2]
            \fill [heavengreen] (-12,-5) rectangle (7,15);
            \draw[line width=2mm,draw=greeen,fill=heavengreen] (0,0) circle (4cm);
            \draw[line width=2mm,draw=gold] (0,0) circle (2cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{ocg}%
}
```